# PHP Reemplazar String por otro String usando Regex (Con texto variable)

Tags: php, regex

**Tengo el siguiente texto en una variable en PHP:**

```
[e https://google.es]Lorem ipsum[/e]
```

**Y quiero transformarlo en:**

```
<a href="https://google.es">Lorem ipsum</a>
```

Tengo otras etiquetas que no son tan complejas y he podido hacerlas con un simple str_replace, pero esta requiere de regex *(supongo)* y hacer que entre `[e`  y `]` pueda haber cualquier contenido, ya me entienden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esta es la regex que buscas:

`\[e (.+)\](.*)\[\/e\]`

Se vé complicada porque hay que escapar los caracteres `[` y `]` porque son caracteres reservados de regex, pero es bastante simple:

`\[e`  que empiece con [e y un espacio. Si puede haber varios espacios ahí, puedes usar \s+

`(.+)` el primer grupo de lo que quieres extraer, una secuencia de 1 o más caracteres.

`\]` cierre del corchete

`(.*)` el segundo grupo que quieres extraer, una secuencia de 0 o más caracteres

`\[/e\]` el cierre del tag e

No estoy muy familiarizado en cómo opera PHP con regex, pero la idea que en los grupos 1 y 2 te quedan los datos que necesitas, luego para crear tu nuevos string, deberías hacer algo así como:

`'<a href="'.$1.'">'.$2.'</a>'`

Edit: en PHP sería algo asi:

```
<?php
$string = '[e https://google.es]Lorem ipsum[/e]';
$pattern = '\[e (.+)\](.*)\[\/e\]';
$replacement = '<a href="$1">$2</a>';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
?>
```